# How to make Lucene search faster?

Tags: java, performance, lucene, indexing

all.
I have 12 large indexes, and each is bigger than 20GB.
My application is trying to make instance of IndexSearcher to search for every request of a user. because the user can select an index which he wants to search.
but the performance of my application is very very very bad.
the user should be wait for about 5 minutes for one search.
my application shows 50 documents per page. and of course I repeat only 50 times to retrieve the data to show using by 'for statement'.
For performance test, I've tried to search using by MatchAllDocsQuery, and it takes about 10 seconds, to find 7,598,870 documents.

I can't know why my application is too slow.

after many times googling...
I've just read a document that says making instance of IndexSearcher is costly.
If I merge all my indexes, it will be 317GB after merge, and then using only one IndexSearcher instance to search w/ filter, it will be faster than before?

please help me. I can't test freely because my application is on customer's intranet.

sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't get more general advice than listed in the [official wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ImproveSearchingSpeed).

However, to answer your point about costly index searcher - the searcher itself is cheap, it is the `IndexReader` which is expensive.

You could potentially cache the 12 readers (for each index), and create [multi searchers](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/ParallelMultiSearcher.html) (if using Lucene 3.6.0) or look at [SlowCompositeReaderWrapper](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/SlowCompositeReaderWrapper.html) for Lucene 4.0+.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My application also makes  and closes IndexReader for every searching. Thanks a lot!! I will modify it!

Comment: Yes, keeping readers open is the first step. If helps, let us know so that further readers could benefit from this. Also, you might want to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this answer - this is how this site works. Thank you!